# iOS swiping/paging between detail pages of Collection View Items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on an iOS app using Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2. I have a collection view that has images and once you tap on the image it takes you to a detail page that has the full-sized image, date and saying displayed. The data for these details are stored in an array and passed from the collection view to the detail page. I want to be able to swipe left or right and go to the previous or next item from the collection view as you would in the photos app.

Is there any built-in functionality that allows for easy paging/swiping, or is a programmatic manipulation of the array index the only way to accomplish this task?

Comment: what have you used for detail Page ScrollView or CollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are familiar with CocoaPods, but there are plenty that can work for you, for example there is SwiftPhotoGallery, but that just maximizes images and let you swipe right and left as you said.

For the specific functionality you describe I would suggest that in the navigation to the "Detail Page" you sent the whole array too, and just show the index of the item tapped in the collection, your "Detail Page" will be a UICollection as well but with a custom cell that takes the whole space of the screen and with a horizontal flow so you can swipe right and left, if you have this code in your github account or any other repository I'll be willing to help to make my point clearer.